# A question about eigenvalues of a special block matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

**Thanks for anyone who views or answers this question!**

$N\times N$ matrix $L$ can be partitioned into $p\times p$ blocks,

$L=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
L_{11} & L_{12} & \cdots & L_{1p}\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                
L_{21} & L_{22} & \cdots & L_{2p}\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                
L_{p1} & L_{p2} & \cdots & L_{pp}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
\end{array}\right]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 $.

Here each row sum of $L_{ij}$ is zero. The square block matrix $L_{ii}$ has some special properties: $l_{mn}\leq 0$, when $m\neq n$, and $l_{mm}=-\sum_{n}{l_{mn}}$。Denote $D=diag\{D_1,D_2,\ldots,D_p\}=diag\{d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_N\}$, where $d_i\geq0$. 
 \begin{equation*}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    \hat{L}=L+D=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}                                                                                                                                                                                                          
\hat{L}_{11} & L_{12} & \cdots & L_{1p}\\                                                                                                                                                                                                          
L_{21} & \hat{L}_{22} & \cdots & L_{2p}\\                                                                                                                                                                                                          
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                
L_{p1} & L_{p2} & \cdots & \hat{L}_{pp}                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{array}\right],                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 \end{equation*}
 There is only one non-zero $d_i>0$ in $D_k\,(k =1,2,\ldots,p)$ such that the eigenvalues of $\hat{L}_{ii}$ are all with positive real parts.
**The question is under what condition the eigenvalues of $\hat{L}$ are all with positive real parts?**